# Registering and using services in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, service, inversion-of-control

In my Rails app, I need to utilize various services. Two of these are 1) a keyring service which decrypts information in the database (given the encryption record id) and 2) a connection pooler which pools and provides access to FTP, SFTP, and S3 connections.

I'm using a small registry to register these and inject these dependencies into controllers.

What I am wondering is: what is the best place to initialize and register these services? Should I create a new initializer (in /config/initializers)? Use application.rb? Or somewhere else?